# Web Forms ASPX designer files not updating

Tags: visual-studio, compiler-errors, webforms, intellisense, designer

I have the following situation:

I have a few aspx pages, but some pages' designer files do not update when adding controls, but some do. I am using git, and this problem exists only on 1 repository, not any others.

I cannot 'Convert to web application'.

I have tried:

- View page in designer > Right click > Refresh.
- Cleaning, building and rebuilding project/solution.
- Unload project > Reload project.
- Changing CodeBehind to CodeFile > Build > Change back to CodeBehind
- Even tried manually adding to the designer from another.

Additional things that might help:

- I do not have any intellisense on the pages that do not update.
- There is no outlining (Collapse/Expand of code) on the pages.

Comment: Add some screenshots of your Visual Studio and the error you get when you try to build, that might give us some clues!

Comment: "I cannot 'Convert to web application'." Don't designer files only exist in web applications? I have web *sites* without designer files.

Comment: @NicoTek I don't get any errors weirdly, I just cannot access any new controls in code behind

Comment: @wazz I put that there because from almost every post I've looked at, that's usually one of the solutions

Comment: On your markup cut everything out, compile, and then paste it and compile again, see if that fixes it. It kinda sounds like your designer file and you code behind might be on a different class or namespace

Comment: @NicoTek sorry for the late reply, that didn't work either unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer (For now), Visual Studio update version 16.10.0 is buggy.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Aspx-files-broken-after-1610-update/1435497